# How to log 4xx errors into sentry?

Tags: node.js, express, sentry

At the moment, server errors with statuses 5xx are logged in sentry.
How can I make errors with the 4xx status be logged as warnings?
Init sentry:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://server.com/8',
  integrations: [
    new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
    new Tracing.Integrations.Express({ app: server }),
    new Tracing.Integrations.Postgres(),
    new ExtraErrorDataIntegration(),
  ],
  environment: 'ENV',
  release: 'n/a',
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  enabled: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**shouldHandleError** intercepts the data.
In this handler, you can change the level

```
server.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler({
  shouldHandleError(error) {
    if (/^[4]/.test(error.statusCode)) {
      Sentry.configureScope((scope) => {
        scope.setLevel(Sentry.Severity.Warning);
      });
    }
    return true;
  },
}));
```